# PHP - image sharpness comparision

Tags: php

I need an algorithm to compare/rate the sharpness of given zones between two images.

For example:
Which image is sharper in the zone given?
Image1 - zone (x:10,y:10) to (x:100,y:100)
Image2 - zone (x:10,y:10) to (x:100,y:100)

the two zones coordinates may not be the same and the zones may vary in area/size.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the average amplitude of the [differential of the image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection). Not exactly rocket science.